# How to access a file within a subdirectory using the Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

Through the Github API, I can access files at the root of the repository just fine, using this URL structure:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents/README.md
```

But let's say README.md is within a subdirectory called 'files'. This does not work (I get a 'not found' error):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents/files/README.md
```

How can I access files in subdirectories?

EDIT: hitting the following gives me all files at the root, and only one of the 10 directories:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents
```

Very odd.

Comment: hit https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents/files and scan through the json objects for readme file, there you should see a key with html_url

Answer (score 0):

You have to hit the raw file.  It looks like your example is just that, so here's a real file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Mptt/master/composer.json